# Homeopathy, etc. - why was my question closed?

Tags: discussion

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7858/what-should-you-say-to-somebody-who-claims-that-homeopathy-just-works

This was my first question on this site, so don't be too harsh!

Is it because the question is too vague? Should I rephrase the question as "Does homeopathy work?". (But I already know the answer to that question... :-)

Is it because my question already contains some answers?

Or is it because my question is more about how it should be answered to convince people than the answer itself?

Any help/advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site. Unfortunately there is no easy way to salvage your question: it's off topic:

> What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> Skeptics - Stack Exchange is for challenging unreferenced notable claims, pseudoscience and biased results. **Skeptics is about applying skepticism — it is for researching the evidence behind claims you encounter. It is not for speculation, philosophical discussions or investigating original claims.**
>
> If you have a question about the accuracy of public claims made in the media or elsewhere, if you're interested in the evidence behind what you hear or read, then you are in the right place.

-From our [FAQ](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)

On the other hand, fortunately we have addressed the topic of homeopathy multiple times. Please see if anything here is of help.

List: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homeopathy

- [Does water have a memory as claimed in homeopathy?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2/does-water-have-a-memory-as-claimed-in-homeopathy)
- [Has most peer-reviewed research on homeopathy given positive results?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6860/has-most-peer-reviewed-research-on-homeopathy-given-positive-results)
- [Is it possible to overdose on Homeopathic medicines?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/100/is-it-possible-to-overdose-on-homeopathic-medicines)
- [Does homeopathic zinc (Zicam) help with the common cold?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/831/does-homeopathic-zinc-zicam-help-with-the-common-cold)

If not, and you are skeptical of a notable claim, feel free to ask a new question.